# Bootstrap popover does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have dynamically loaded content in my HTML document. So I can't use jQuery's click function for those elements which were added at a later point in time. I have just set the popover *trigger* to *manual* combined with jQuerys *on* function, but it still does not work. Please take a look at my code.

```
$(".dynamic-element").popover({
    placement : 'left',
    title : 'Title',
    content : 'Content',
    trigger : 'manual'
}).on("click", ".dynamic-element", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML.

Comment: If `.dynamic-element` is not in html, the plugin will not work. You need to put invocation of the plugin to click handler.